# Prove that every convex polygon with area $1$ is contained in a parallelogram of area $\frac{4}{3}$

Tags: geometry, area, combinatorial-geometry

> Prove that every convex polygon with area $1$ is contained in a parallelogram of area $\frac{4}{3}$

I can only show that polygon is contained in a rectangle of area $2$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

This is the best result, because the smallest area of a polygon which has a center of symmetry and contains a given triangle of area 1 is 2, see [D.O. Shklyarskiy, N.N. Chentsov, I.M.Yaglom “Geomerical estimations and combinatorial geometry problems”, Moskow, Nauka, 19741, Problem 52.b (in Russian)](http://ilib.mccme.ru/djvu/bib-mat-kr/shk-13.djvu?djvuopts&page=42)). In particural, no triangle of area 1 is contained in a parallelogram of area less than 2.